Biographical details of Isador M. Sheffer
The Sheffer sequence of polynomials satisfies conditions that are related to the umbral calculus. They are named after the American mathematician Isador M. Sheffer. He obtained his PhD degree at Harvard University under the supervision of George Birkhoff. Moreover, he was a professor of mathematics at Pennsylvania State University.
Besides these facts - which I found in the short wiki article on this mathematician - I could find little biographical information about this person. Are there any sources that describe his life and mathematical contributions in more detail?

some here

According to the MacTutor article on the mathematical logician Henry Maurice Sheffer, Isador Mitchell Sheffer was his youngest brother, born in Boston, Massachusetts in 1901. The Sheffer family was Jewish and originally came from a region of the Russian Empire near the city of Odessa 1 (now: Odesa, Ukraine), immigrating to the Unites States in the early 1890s.
There seems to be a bit of confusion about I. M. Sheffer's birth date. The MacTutor article on H. M. Sheffer states October 14, while the Wikipedia article on I. M. Sheffer states October 15. Neither of these seem to be correct. An OCRed Google snippet from the Harvard Class Album of 1923 shows Isador's birthday as October 4, 1901. This is corroborated by the entry for I. M. Sheffer in Jacques Cattell (ed.), American Men of Science: A Biographical Directory, 8th ed. Lancaster, PA: The Science Press 1949, p. 2252.
Sheffer studied mathematics at Harvard from 1919 to 1923, when he received his S.B. magna cum laude. According to the 1923 Harvard Alumni Directory, p. 750, he resided at 100 Nightingale St. in Dorchester, a neighborhood of Boston with a large Jewish population. Located directly across the street was Congregation Chai Odom at 101 Nightingale St.
In 1924 Sheffer received his master's degree at Rice Institute (now: Rice University). He appears to have stayed on for a bit, as his first publication dating to 1926 shows Rice as his academic affiliation.
In 1927 I. M. Sheffer received his Ph.D. from Harvard. The title of his dissertation was On the Theory of Linear Differential Equations of Infinite Order; his advisor was George David Birkhoff. Subsequently he became an instructor at the University of Michigan. Official Register of Harvard University, Vol. XXIV, March 9, 1927, No. 8, p. 106:

ISADOR MITCHELL SHEFFER SB 1923, SM (Rice Inst.) 1924. Subject, Mathematics. Special Field, Analysis. Thesis, "On the Theory of Linear Differential Equations of Infinite Order". Instructor in Mathematics, University of Michigan.

The official register of Princeton University, The Catalogue, Vol. XX, No. 2, Nov. 1928, p. 441 lists Sheffer as a visiting fellow for the academic year 1928-1929. In September 1929 Sheffer joined the faculty of Pennsylvania State College as an assistant professor, became an associate professor in 1934, and full professor in 1940. He stayed with this institution until he became professor emeritus in 1969.
The entry for Shaffer in Cattell's biographical directory indicates that he married in 1928, but no children. Data from the 1940 census shows Isador M. Sheffer residing in West Foster Avenue, State College, PA, with his spouse Flora Sheffer, both age 38, with no children present in the household.
The following death notice appeared in Notices of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 39, No. 8, Oct. 1992, p. 959:

Isador M. Sheffer, of Warm Mineral Springs, Florida, died on July 20, 1992, at the age of 90. He was a member of the Society for 65 years.

Harvard Magazine, Vol. 95, 1992, p. 94:

ISADOR MITCHELL SHEFFER '23mcl, Ph.D. '27, of Warm Mineral Spring, Fla., died July 20

Penn State Intercom, Vol. 22, No. 1, August 20, 1992, p.14:

Isador  M.  Sheffer,  professor  emeritus of  mathematics,  died  July  20  at  the  age of  90. He  received  a  bachelor  of  science degree  in  mathematics  in  1923  from Harvard  University,  a  master's  of  science in  1925  from  Rice  University,  and a  doctorate  from  Harvard  in  1927. Dr.  Sheffer  joined  the  faculty  Sept. 1,  1929,  and  retired  July  1,  1969.  In 1960,  he  received  the  University's Citation  for  Excellence  in  Teaching.


1 MacTutor states that Henry M. Sheffer was born in Odesa, but this is likely incorrect.
The Reform Advocate, Vol. LII, No. 10, October 14, 1916, pp. 307-308:

Dr. Sheffer was born in the little town of Baltu in the province of Podolyia near the Austrian border in Russia. His family came to America when he was eleven years old.

The historic region of Podolia is located in what is now western Ukraine. While I cannot locate a town named Baltu in it, a Russian map from around 1900 provided by Wikipedia shows the town of Балта (Balta) at the southern border of the Russian administrative region of Podolia, about 200km north of Odesa. It seems likely that this is where the Sheffer family resided prior to moving to the United States.

List of publications of Isidor Mitchell Sheffer:
I. M. Sheffer, "Systems of equations in an infinity of unknowns, whose solution involves an arbitrary parameter." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 28, No. 2, Apr. 1926, pp. 266-286
I. M. Sheffer, "On entire function interpolation." American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 49, No. 3, Jul. 1927, pp. 329-342
I. M. Sheffer, "Systems of linear differential equations of infinite order, with constant coefficients." Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 30, No. 1/4, 1928, pp. 250-264
I. M. Sheffer, "Linear Differential Equations of Infinite Order, With Polynomial Coefficients of Degree One." Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 30, No. 1/4, 1928, pp. 345-372
I. M. Sheffer, "A proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 35, No. 2, Mar. 1929, pp. 227-230
I. M. Sheffer, "Expansions in generalized Appell polynomials, and a class of related linear functional equations.", Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 31, No. 2, Apr. 1929, pp. 261-280
I. M. Sheffer, "Systems of infinitely many linear differential equations of infinite order, with constant coefficients." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 31, No. 2, Apr. 1929, pp. 281-289
I. M. Sheffer, "A Note on Matrix Power Series." The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 37, No. 5, May 1930, pp. 228-231
I. M. Sheffer, "An aspect of the theory of linear differential equations." Tohoku Mathematical Journal, First Series, Vol. 39, 1934, pp. 299-315
I. M. Sheffer, "On the properties of polynomials satisfying a linear differential equation: Part I." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 35, No. 1, Jan. 1935, pp. 184-214
I. M. Sheffer, "Concerning some methods of best approximation, and a theorem of Birkhoff." American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 57, No. 3, Jul. 1935, pp. 587-614
I. M. Sheffer, "Note on non-analytic functions." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 41, No. 6, Jun. 1935, pp. 367-372
I. M. Sheffer, "A differential equation for Appell polynomials." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 41, No. 12, Dec. 1935, pp. 914-923
I. M. Sheffer, "A local solution of the difference equation $\Delta y(x) = F(x)$ and of related equations." Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 39, No. 3, May 1936, pp. 345-379
I. M. Sheffer, "A simplified solution of the equation $\Delta y(x) = F(x)$." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 43, No. 4, Apr. 1937, pp. 283-287
I. M. Sheffer, "Concerning Appell sets and associated linear functional equations." Duke Mathematical Journal, Vol. 3, No. 4, Dec. 1937, pp. 593-609
I. M. Sheffer, "Some properties of polynomial sets of type zero." Duke Mathematical Journal, Vol. 5, No. 3, Sep. 1939, pp. 590-622
I. M. Sheffer, "Some applications of certain polynomial classes." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 47, No. 12.P1, Dec. 1941, pp. 885-898
I. M. Sheffer, "Systems of equations of analytic type." Duke Mathematical Journal, Vol. 11, No. 1, Mar. 1944, pp. 167-180
I. M. Sheffer, "An extension of a Perron system of linear equations in infinitely many unknowns.",  American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 67, No. 1, Jan. 1945, pp. 123-140
I. M. Sheffer, "Convergence of multiply-infinite series." The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 52, No. 7, Aug. 1945, pp. 365-376
I. M. Sheffer, "Note on Appel polynomials." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 51, No. 10, Oct. 1945, pp. 739-744
I. M. Sheffer, "Note on multiply-infinite series." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 52, No. 12, Dec. 1946, pp. 1036-1041
I. M. Sheffer, "Some limit theorems." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 54, No. 2, Feb, 1948, pp. 219-231
I. M. Sheffer, "On the theory of sum-equations." Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 55, No. 8, Aug. 1949, pp. 777-788
I. M. Sheffer, "On the Solution of Sum-Equations." American Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 72, No. 4, Oct. 1950, pp. 835-848
I. M. Sheffer, "The Derivatives of Certain Functions." The Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society, Vol. 16, 1952, pp. 83-97
I. M. Sheffer, "A class of functions related to harmonic functions." Duke Mathematical Journal, Vol. 21, No. 3, Sep. 1954, pp. 479-489
H. L. Krall and I. M. Sheffer, "Some solution-preserving operators for a partial differential equation." Duke Mathematical Journal, Vol. 30, No. 4, Dec. 1963, pp. 615-635
H. L. Krall and I. M. Sheffer, "A characterization of orthogonal polynomials." Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Vol. 8, 1964, pp. 232-244.
H. L. Krall and I. M. Sheffer, "Differential equations of infinite order for orthogonal polynomials." Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata, Vol. 74, No. 1, Dec. 1966, pp. 135-172
H. L. Krall and I. M. Sheffer, "Orthogonal polynomials in two variables." Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata, Vol. 76, 1967, pp. 325-376
H. L. Krall and I. M. Sheffer, "Difference equations for some orthogonal polynomials." Pacific Journal of Mathematics, Vol. 28, No. 2, Jan. 1969, pp. 383-392
H. L. Krall and I. M. Sheffer, "On Trigonometric Polynomials Satisfying Differential Equations." The Journal of the Indian Mathematical Society, Vol. 39, No. 1-4, Mar.-Dec. 1975, pp. 29-49

The spell checker has not picked up that you meant stayed, not staid.
